# VeracityLearning LRS (LRS.io) local installation

Tags: lrs

I'm trying to install the Veracity Learning LRS locally (on Windows). I followed [this guide](https://lrs.io/docs/manual/versions/#Installation) exactly, and MongoDB is installed and running with no apparent problems. However, I get a strange TypeError when I try to save the configuration:

```
Console:    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js Some OSs will require you to run with administrator rights to bind to your selected port.
Console:    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js Cannot convert undefined or null to object
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
    at v (C:\snapshot\lrs2\build\lite\manager.js:2185:795751)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async C:\snapshot\lrs2\build\lite\manager.js:2185:796007
```

The given file locations don't exist on my machine, so I don't know where to look to debug this. I've also tried to run the command prompt as administrator, which removes the first message but not the second. Has anyone encountered this issue before? I'm also not committed to the Veracity LRS, so I'm also open to suggestions for a simpler installation; this was only supposed to be for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from Veracity, and this is an issue that cropped up on some configurations a while ago, but we've not seen it in a long time, so either the bug has reappeared or you just have an older version.

If you're not using 1.10.x, make sure to try the latest version.

Comment: I believe I was using the latest version, but I can go back and check. I downloaded the zip in the /latest folder, wouldn't that be it?

Comment: That issue was last seen in 1.7.x, current is 1.10.x

Comment: You're correct, I have no idea how I ended up with the older version but it appears I downloaded 1.7.1. I've accepted the answer and mods can feel free to delete this question, since it was just a matter of me using the wrong version.